# Camera Output in fullscreen - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, camera, fullscreen

I'm working on augmented reality and I wanted to know if it was possible to get the camera output in fullscreen with a normal scale. I'm currently able to get a deformed output (everything is larger than in the real world).

Edit:
I found in the PhotoCamera class on msdn that I have to use camera.AvailableResolutions. This returns an IEnumrable of Size, each one being a supported resolution.

Comment: Could you add pictures of the current effect and of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I'll try to make some pictures ASAP

Comment: I am a bit worried about this: "everything is larger than in the real world" how are you comparing the real world and the picture? You will have to take camera attributes such as zoom and dpi and screen attributes such as zoom and dpi but also distance into consideration.

Comment: If my phone is landscape oriented the environnement is larger than expected, and if I have my phone portrait oriented the environment is thiner.

Comment: I do not understand this. Do you mean to say that the aspect ratio is wrong; squares becoming rectangular? Could it be that you are displaying/stretching the picture incorrectly?

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean, the image is stretched because the camera is taking an image in 640x480 and the screen is in 800x480.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I do not understand this. Do you mean to say that the aspect ratio is
>   wrong; squares becoming rectangular? Could it be that you are
>   displaying/stretching the picture incorrectly?
>
> Yeah that's what I mean, the image is stretched because the camera is taking an image in 640x480 and the screen is in 800x480

In the UI where you display the image, set the Stretch to `None`, `Uniform` or `UniformToFill`. Do not use `Fill` that will distort the image.

```
<Image Source="..." Stretch="Uniform" />
```

[See these examples on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Each phone has different lens focal length and screen size. There is no API to scale camera output to physical dimensions of real world (to see the world on the screen like through transparent window). Also, the distance from user eyes to the phone is affected to what should be displayed. You could experimentally find average scale factor to best map camera output to phone screen.

**EDIT:**
From the beginning it was like the question was not about distortions on different screen orientations but like augmented reality problem.

Comment: WP7 forces a specific camera resolution no? Must be something like 640*480 for the camera I think

Comment: Question was modified from augmented reality and right scale to see world on the screen like it is to just a `Stretch` of `Image` control in different orientations.